# Can the build policies on a pull request in Azure Devops use the yaml-files that is updated in said PR?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have all our pipelines checked into code, but if we deliver a PR with changes in those pipelines, the PR Build Policies will run with the YAML-files in MASTER, not the ones that we want to check into master. It's basically a deadlock.

Say you want to remove a validation that makes all your PRs fail, so you make a PR but you can't merge it cause the build policies fail :P

PS: I know I can remove the policies, complete the merge, and add the policies back in as a manual job, but that is not really a good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a separate yaml pipeline with the pre merge build steps that you then set in the PR policies for. It will always run the code from the current branch that the PR is created from.

We do it like this:
(All in same repo)

1. build_steps.yml - Yaml template with build steps
2. azure-pipelines-yml - Main pipeline that has a reference to build_steps.yml to build the project
3. pre_merge.yml - Secondary pipeline that is run only by PR request which has a reference to build_steps.yml so there are no differences in the build and two places to update if something changes.

Whole yaml definition:

```yaml
#pre_merge.yml
trigger: none #Pipeline should never trigger on any branches. Only invoked by the policy.

variables:
  - name: system.buildConfiguration 
    value: 'Release'

  - name: system.buildPlatform
    value: 'win10-x86'

  - name: system.debug
    value: 'false'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

name: $(SourceBranchName)_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)

steps:
- template: build_steps.yml
```

And then in the policies you setup it like this:
[image]

All this applies also to classic pipelines. You need to create a seperate pre-merge build pipeline that could reference a TaskGroup with the steps used in the main build pipeline. In both cases you dont have to use a template or Taskgroup and and create the steps manually. But if the build would change in the future you have 2 places to update.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in debt answer. We got this working in a short amount of time!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are saying that the pre-merge pipeline itself is taken from the target branch of the PR (the protected branch), so no significant changes should take place there, but the template is taken from the source branch? Otherwise, I do not understand how this solves the issue.

Comment: @Palec The Pre-Merge Pipeline builds according to what is on the target branch (The branch where you have your changes).  And the Pipeline template is also taken from there. Not sure why you think it should take it from the source branch. Tho if you really would like to achieve this, its also possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there as an alternative. However; if desired can maintain one yaml pipeline that can do both the pre merge and the deployment.

Would want to create a variable to detect if the pipeline is running against the "master/main" branch similar to:

```
  IsMainBranch: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]
```

From there the variable will need to be a condition on subsequent jobs/stages.  Personally I do not like this approach as it limits the portability of the pipelines.  In addition it interjects another variable to account for; however, felt it fair to provide an alternative option.

Answer (score 0):

Privileged enough users may override the branch policies and complete the PR even though the policy fails. A reason for the override needs to be specified and it becomes a part of the PR's history.

The privilege on the repository or branch is called "Bypass policies when completing pull requests" and the override of the policies is activated when completing the PR via a checkbox, which is present in the dialog only for those having the privilege. To address a common confusion: policy override is not available when setting auto-complete -- it is available only when actually completing the PR.

See the documentation of [bypassing branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#bypass-branch-policies) and [PR completion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/complete-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#complete-a-pull-request). See Eric L. Anderson's blog for [a full walk-through with screenshots](https://elanderson.net/2020/05/azure-devops-repos-bypass-branch-policies/).